# What can I use as a substitute to FxSound now that I am on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound

I'm looking for an app that would do the job of [FxSound](https://www.fxsound.com/) but on Linux.
I've tried something called PulseEffects but it's far too complicated and has almost no presets.

Thx for any suggestion :)